# Change the background color of a CDateTimeCtrl

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a MFC `CDateTimeCtrl` object in my MFC based Dialog.
My question is, how can I change the background color and the text color of the edit box ?

After an extensive search I tried the following code for a subclassed `CDateTimeCtrl` but this shows my background color only if I click in the `DateTimeCtrl` box.

```
BOOL CCHDateTimeCtrl::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC *pDC)
{
    CRect rect;
    pDC->GetClipBox(&rect);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(&rect, getBackgroundColor());
    return TRUE;
}
```

Hopefully someone has a suggestion.

Comment: I have a customised `CDateTimeCtrl` in my project(s) and its `OnEraseBackground` override is very similar to yours. I even changed it to be even more like yours, and it works without issue. Do you "do anything" to your control in the parent's `OnInitDialog` override ... anything would would force a repaint? Maybe just add an *explicit* `GetDlgItem(IDD_MYDTC)->RedrawWindow()` at initialization time?

Comment: And, just to be sure (no offence intended) ... did you add the `ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()` to the message map for the `CCHDateTimeCtrl` class?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for answering.
I have indeed ON_WM_ERASEBKGND() added to my message map.

Comment: A mydtc->RedrawWindow in the OnInitDialog does not help.

My customised CDateTimeCtrl is created from a windows resource and through SubclassDlgItem coupled to my custom datetime picker.

Comment: On the web site of codeproject.com there is a solution written in C#.
It overrides the OnPaint method but for instance the last instruction (ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(...)) is not possible from MFC.

Comment: I doubt a GDI thing is possible in C# and not in MFC...

Comment: And the solution you are speaking about is: [A DateTimePicker with working BackColor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30660/A-DateTimePicker-with-working-BackColor)

Comment: Indeed that solution I was referring to.

Separate access to the MFC ComboBox drop down button is not available in MFC.
I have changed that Codeproject solution by not drawing the Combobox button in my OnPaint.

I do start with a call to the CDateTimeCtrl OnPaint method and then erase the background minus 15 pixels, the width of that button, and then draw the text.

That works, only text selection and text entry is a remaining challenge which I hopefully will be able to resolve.
If you know how to handle that please give a hint.